# How can I fix slow FTP download in Android app on Android 12 and 13?

Tags: android, ftp, android-12, android-13

I am currently updating an Android app which downloads a file of about 200MB using FTP.

This app has been in live for several years with no reported problems.

Testing on AWS Device Farm with some Android 12 and 13 devices the download is extremely slow. It's taking about 2000 seconds compared with about 30 seconds on Android 11 devices, also on AWS.

It is slow on all the Android 13 devices I have tested, Google Pixel 6A and Google Pixel 7 Pro. However with Android 12 it's slow on the Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra 5G but normal speed on the Google Pixel 6.

I'm using the **FTPClientFunctions** class in Java. Originally I had set
`mFTPClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024);` but trying to fix this issue I increased this to `mFTPClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024*10);`. This produced faster download on some devices but not on the very slow ones where there was no change in speed at all. Increasing this value more doesn't make any difference and making it too big causes the app to crash.

My FTPClient setup currently looks like:

```
public class FTPClientFunctions {

    public FTPClient mFTPClient = null;

    public boolean ftpConnect(String host, String username, String password, int port) {
        try {
            mFTPClient = new FTPClient();
            // connecting to the host
            mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
            // now check the reply code, if positive mean connection success
            if (FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(mFTPClient.getReplyCode())) {
                // login using username & password
                boolean status = mFTPClient.login(username, password);
         
                mFTPClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                mFTPClient.setBufferSize(1024*1024);

                return status;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Global.log("Error: could not connect to host " + host);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I'm instanciating this with:

```
ftpStatus = ftpClientFunctions.ftpConnect("ftp.myserver.com", "ussername", "password", 21);
```

This is running on a sub thread which is started with:
`new Thread(() -> {`

I haven't been able to find any evidence that this is a known issue. Unfortunately I don't have an Android 13 device to test on apart from what's in the AWS Device Farm (which are real devices).

Is there a new feature in Android 12 and 13 which might be causing this and what do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: What is FtpClientFunctions? And why are there both .connect() and .ftpConnect()?

Comment: Excuse me, FtpClientFunctions was a typo. I have corrected and added more detail. ftpConnect is instanciating the class ```FTPClientFunctions``` which opens the connection with ```mFTPClient.connect(host, port);```

Comment: You should post the download code i think.